# Why are [my] CSS3/jQuery transitions so imperfectly smooth, and how do I make them more smooth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

As much as I've searched for information about this all over the internet, I can't find *anything* about it, so I've come here for help.

What's been bugging me: That no matter which method I use -- a jQuery .animate, or a css3 transition, [my] animations don't appear to be perfectly smooth. I didn't understand why they appear this way at first, and it's so subtle I ended up having to do some video capping to prove it. But it's definitely there -- the animations are juttery. Sometimes a frame happens too fast, and sometimes too slow.

Flip it back and forth six or seven times, and you'll hopefully see what I'm talking about.

I can understand this with jQuery -- JS execution isn't perfect. A quick profiling shows that indeed, when using jQuery anim, some frames get triggered too soon and some frames are late. But with CSS3?

What do people do to solve this problem?

Comment: If it does only run on Webkit with such simple kind of animation, there is a bug in your code.

Comment: The animation runs fine on other browsers -- it's the triggering i didn't bother to cater specifically to FF. I'd ask you to actually look at the code (the animation function is only a few lines) before you make that kind of snap judgement.

Comment: the performance of a webpage all depends on the browser you use, its version, the machine you use, and what are concurrently running. i agree with @powtac, there must be a bug, or it's just your code not optimized. try researching how DOM manipulations affect performance, JS benchmarks for browsers, and try researching the browsers themselves and what they are capable of.

Comment: Just thought I'd say I am NOT a beginner coder, which both of you seem to be assuming I am. Not sure of any kinder way to say that -- this is only a single property manipulation on a single DOM object, and if you read the code you'd see that.

Answer (score 0):

Set this JS before your code:

```
jQuery.fx.interval = 100;
```

Comment: I've tried that -- also, this both isn't a frame rate issue (it's a consistency one -- and although increasing frame rate can reduce the perception of a consistency issue, I find it doesn't really help in this case for some reason) nor is it solely a jQuery issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am moving the container using the `margin-left` CSS property and [`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) of jQuery and is pretty smooth. Use the arrow keys to use it (left and right)

The current version of that project its now full of images, text, iframes and is still smooth.

Comment: So that helps slightly, but only because you're using EaseInOutExpo, which somewhat masks the effect. Use a function like the default swing, or EaseInOutQuart (my preference) and the imperfections are more evident on any reasonably 'average' machine.

Comment: I've tested on two machines by the way, and I see the same effects with your code when switched to EaseInOutQuart -- animations are not perfectly smooth, and while they're satisfactory, they aren't *perfect*. I'm sure I've seen sites that work around it without resorting to quick movement tricks. So how do they do that?

Comment: Show me the url of one and i will tell you.

Comment: The MegaUpload link is dead and was removed from the post. Please consider updating it again.

Comment: This was answered 7 years ago, I no longer have such files; anyway rendering has come a long way and this question is probably no longer relevant (at least for CSS3 implementations).